# Метки "миграция" и "перенос-вопросов"

Tags: предложение, метки, хэшкод, переименование-метки

Обратил внимание, что сейчас на Мете присутствует две схожие на основании названия, но разные по сути метки. Первая [миграция](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), вторая [перенос-вопросов](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2). Если не читать их описание, то на первый взгляд может показаться, что метки об одном и том же. Однако, это не так. Даже у меня оказались некоторые старые вопросы тут, которые были помечены неправильной меткой.

В связи с этим, предлагаю сделать следующее (нужны будут действия со стороны держателей ромбов):

- Переименовать метку [миграция](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) в [миграция-хэшкод](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%85%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4), чтобы сразу из названия была видна суть метки.
- К метке [перенос-вопросов](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2) добавить синоним [миграция](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (уже не связанная с хэшкод метка). Дополнительно можно добавить синоним [миграция-вопросов](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2), но это уже не обязательно.

Почему важно сделать метку [миграция](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) связанной именно с переносом вопросов между сайтами SE. Оригинально механизм называется "migration", с таким же словом идут англоязычные фразы, связанные с переносом вопросов.
На MSE соответствующая метка так и называется [[migration]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration).
Механизм переноса вопросов между сайтами SE является действующим в отличии от произошедшего давным давно переноса содержимого (вопросы, ответы, комментарии, пользователи, репутация и т.д.) ХэшКода в базу StackOverflow. На текущий момент долетают только редкие архаичные проблемы этого переноса. Проблемы, которые с большой вероятностью никто исправлять не будет. Например, казалось бы основополагающий момент сайтов SE - репутация. Но даже явные [косяки с её начислением](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291897/339911) при преобразовании ХэшКода в "StackOverflow на русском" исправлять совсем не торопятся.